# How to remove the username from Git

Tags: git, android-studio

The problem is that I want to move a project from one repository to another.
In the first project, several users made `commits`.

But on the second repository where I want to upload the project, I want to remove the username and keep his `commits`.

For example: in the first project, users `A`, `B`, `C`.
But on the second project, `A` and `B` users should remain, but commits from user `C` should remain. Write `C` commits under user `A` or `B`

Tell me, what kind of command can I remove the user?

Comment: Locate all commits of this user, and `--amend` them with `--author="Somebody<somebody@gmail.com>"`

Answer (score 0):

You would use git filter-branch, here is a snippet for the filter you'd use

Please note filter-branch makes it easy to break things. It also changes your hashes. Please read up on it in the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to avoid causing problems. With anything this drastic, make sure your backups are in order.

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter '
WRONG_EMAIL="wrong@example.com"
NEW_NAME="New Name Value"
NEW_EMAIL="correct@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

source: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email